# WooCommerce - Update All Product Descriptions (site-wide) on Button Press

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, plugins

I have been playing around with the following code in the hope that I will be able to create a button - press it - and then all the descriptions on my website will auto generate. The dream.

***My question: Why is my code not updating ALL of the products as intended?***

So far I have the following code, which although it works to an extent, doesn't work correctly when the button is located on a product page - It will update that product pages description along with all empty description instances for product with an ID greater than the current product, but doesn't include anything below?!

I have been using the following post to try and help me get to an answer: [Woocommerce: function to update all products](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55965302/woocommerce-function-to-update-all-products) however I have so far been unsuccessful!

My current code:

```
// EDIT ALL PRODUCTS //

add_action( 'woocommerce_admin_process_product_object', 'update_products_by_x' );
function update_products_by_x(){
    
    if(isset($_POST['button_all_descriptions']) && $_POST['button_all_descriptions'] == 'All_Descriptions'){
    
        $product_all = get_posts( array(
            'post_type'        => 'product','product_variation',
            'post_status'      => 'publish','future','draft','pending','private','trash','auto-draft','inherit',
            'fields'           => 'ids'
        ) );

        // Loop through product Ids
        foreach ( $product_all as $product_id ) {
    
            // Get the WC_Product object
            $WCproduct = wc_get_product($product_id);
            
                if($WCproduct->is_type('simple') or $WCproduct->is_type('variable')){
                
                    $title = $WCproduct->get_name();
                    $mpn = $WCproduct->get_meta('sp_wc_barcode_field');
                    $description = $WCproduct->get_description();
                    $output = '';
                    
                    if(!empty($title)){
            
                        $output .= "<p>A " . $title;
                    
                    }if(!empty($mpn)){

                        $output .= " (MPN: " . $mpn . ").";             
                    
                    }if(empty($description)){
                        
                        $WCproduct->set_description($output);
                        $WCproduct->save();
                        
                    }   
                }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might have a default limit of results restricting number of products your `get_posts` call returns

```
$product_all = get_posts( array(
    'post_type'        => 'product','product_variation',
    'post_status'      => 'publish','future','draft','pending','private','trash','auto-draft','inherit',
    'fields'           => 'ids',
    'numberposts'      => -1
) );
```

Comment: Sometimes the simplest solutions are the best! This is perfect for small levels of data, if I were to start generating more than 200 descriptions at a time, it would most likely be better to set the ```'numberposts'      => -1``` to something like ```'numberposts'      => 200```